# Le subjonctif ou l’indicatif?

Tags: grammaire, expressions, usage

J’ai besoin de votre aide! Dans ces deux phrases, les verbes sont-ils conjugués au  présent du subjonctif ou de l’indicatif ? Et pourquoi? Merci d’avance~

1. C’est la chose la plus intéressante que je trouve.
2. Il est la seule personne que j’aime.

Comment: La deuxième est un calque de l'anglais. En français, on dit plutôt: ***C'est** la seule personne que j'aime*.

Answer (score 1):

Comme la première phrase n'est correcte que dans un contexte très rare il ne peut pas s'agir de ce contexte et elle est donc fausse par rapport avec ce qui devait être exprimé; de plus le verbe particulier choisi n'est pas clair; en conséquence une variété de possibilités ont été considérées dans la présente réponse.

**A** Si l'intention de la personne est de dire que parmi  toutes les choses qu'elle a trouvées celle qu'elle désigne est la plus intéressante, alors la nature du verbe est sans ambigüité et il faut utiliser le subjonctif. Dans la langue traditionnelle il faut écrire et dire ceci.

> C'est la chose la plus intéressante que j'aie trouvée.

La raison de cette utilisation du subjonctif est plus ou moins une question d'usage. Cela est attesté par les assertions suivantes dues à la [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=5168);

« On emploie plus souvent le subjonctif que l’indicatif après un superlatif ou l’équivalent d’un superlatif, notamment le seul (la seule) qui, le seul que, le seul dont, l’unique qui, le premier qui, le dernier que, le meilleur que, ainsi qu’après il n’y a que… qui (que, dont, etc.) et il y a peu de… que. »

Sinon le problème n'est pas un problème de mode mais une question de contexte et de construction correspondante et en plus de choix de verbe; tout dépend du contexte dans lequel se trouve la personne qui parle.

**1.** Le verbe utilisé dans la première phrase est le verbe défini comme suit.

> Trouver qqc./qqn + attribut
>   a) [Le compl. d'obj. désigne une chose concr. ou abstr.] **Considérer quelque chose de telle manière.**

Dans ce cas la construction de la phrase ne convient pas. Il faut la construire comme suit.

a. Si la personne qui parle se réfère à un ensemble de choses précis et qu'elle émet une comparaison alors la construction suivante est correcte.

- C'est la chose que je trouve la plus intéressante. (*Le mode est l'indicatif, le temps est le présent.*)

b. Si la personne qui parle ne fait pas une comparaison et qu'elle a l'intention d'exprimer que la chose est parmi des chose très intéressantes la construction ne peut plus comprendre « la plus ».

- C'est une chose que je trouve très intéressante.(*indicatif présent.*)
- (*similaire*) C'est une chose que je trouve des plus intéressantes.

**2.** Le verbe dans la première phrase est le verbe défini comme suit.

> A. **Découvrir quelque chose, quelqu'un que l'on cherchait**

Dans ce cas il y a trois possibilités de base.

a. La première est correspond à un contexte rare et la construction est celle proposée; le contexte est celui d'un ensemble de chose connues mais dont on ne sait pas laquelle peut être appliquée à une situation donnée et parmi ces choses possibles il y en a une qui est la plus intéressante et bien sûr la personne qui parle est en train de chercher.

- C'est la chose la plus intéressante que je trouve. (*indicatif présent*)

b. La personne qui parle est impliquée en même temps qu'elle parle dans le processus de recherche qui justifie ce qu'elle dit et plusieurs constructions sont possibles mais pas celle proposée; il n'y a pas comme dans le cas précédent d'ensemble défini de chose dont une serait le résultat de la recherche. La raison pour ne pas pouvoir utiliser le pronom démonstratif « ce » (c') est que lorsque l'on dit « C'est la chose…», du fait que l'on utilise un démonstratif pour la chose, on signifie une chose dont on a déjà parlé, qu'on connait dans le dialogue, ce qui n'est pas possible puisque on est en train de la découvrir.

- Cette chose que je trouve est des plus intéressantes. (*L'adjectif démonstratif est utilisable parce qu'il a comme référent non pas une chose connue, dont il aurait été question dans le dialogue mais  la chose « **que je trouve** »*)

c. La personne qui parle a trouvé la chose donnée un certain temps avant de parler.

- C'est une chose des plus intéressantes que je viens de trouver. (*aussi*) C'est une des choses les plus intéressantes que je viens de trouver. (*passé récent*)
- C'est une chose des plus intéressantes que j'ai trouvé. (*aussi*) C'est une des choses les plus intéressantes que j'ai trouvé. (***passé composé*** et non subjonctif passé)

**B** Il n'y a aucun problème pour la seconde phrase. Le mode de son verbe est le subjonctif. La difficulté est de faire la différence entre l'indicatif et le subjonctif au présent parce que les verbes du premier groupe ont la même forme. Lorsque l'on a acquis une certaine habitude de la langue cette difficulté persistera encore pendant longtemps, cependant on aura alors l'habitude des verbes du troisième groupe dans ce « territoire »; il suffira alors de substituer un verbe du troisième groupe pour vérifier que l'on est bien en « territoire du subjonctif ». Avec « connaitre » on se sera rappelé qu'il faut dire « C'est la seule personne que je connaisse. » et on saura qu'il s'agit du subjonctif. La raison pour le subjonctif est la même qu'au « **A** » ci-dessus.

Comment: Merci à toi, LPH.

Comment: @user17676 You welcome, I hope it's not too difficult to read.

Answer (score -2):

Pas la moindre nuance de doute ou d'hypothèse. => mode **indicatif** dans les deux cas.

Tu pourrais aussi écrire :

- Que j'ai trouvé, que je trouverai, que je peux trouver, je sais trouver... tous des indicatifs.
- Que j'ai aimé, que j'aimais, que j'aimerai... tous des indicatifs aussi.

---

**EDIT** en réponse à l'objection formulée par Eau qui dort en commentaires :

Je ramène l'expression honnête d'une opinion à l'expression du doute (c'est la moindre des choses depuis Montaigne). L'utilisation du subjonctif pour l'abstraction n'est, à mon sens, qu'une affaire de style. v.g. on peut ou on peut ne pas. En matière d'abstraction pure, je ne connais aucun théorème mathématique usant du subjonctif, pour ne rien dire des philosophies.

Oui, le subjonctif peut être aussi utilisé pour formuler des impératifs de politesse, mais ceci est une autre histoire et là encore, affaire de style.

Dans aucune des phrases de l'OP, le subjectif ne s'impose donc **grammaticalement**. Elles ne font pas non plus montre d'une recherche stylistique particulière. Pourquoi alors faire des nœuds au cerveau d'un apprenant ?

Comment: Le subjonctif est juste utilisé pour exprimer la doute ou l’hypothèse,?

Comment: @user17676 : à notre époque, on peut dire que grosso-modo oui. Le subjonctif est un mode. En tant que tel, il communique une **valeur**.

Comment: En français, on présente une information d’une manière objective par les temps de l’indicatif et d’une manière subjective par le subjonctive, non? Je crois que le deuxième cas c’est le subjonctif parce qu’il est juste la seule personne pour ce qui parle. Cela est totalement subjectif. Avec les autres, il n’est pas la seul personne qu’ils aiment.

Comment: @user17676 : Je n'ai pas forcément bien compris ton objection. Que l'amour soit un sentiment subjectif est certain. Mais ceci ne rentre pas en compte dans la détermination du mode. On peut être subjectif dans la constance et la certitude et c'est bien ce qu'exprime la subordonnée. C'est la seule personne que tu *dessines, grondes, n'aimes pas, surprends, défends, crois, attaques...* Indicatif partout sans la moindre hésitation.

Comment: Je comprends pas encore. Start getting confused.

Comment: Il y a plus que le doute ou l'hypothèse qui implique l'usage d'un subjonctif, c'est aussi le mode utilisé pour les idées abstraites, y compris les opinions présentées comme telles (de manière inhérente, elles sont non-factuelles). c'est bien le cas dans les deux phrases de l'OP qui conviendraient très bien, et de manière conforme à l'usage, avec un subjonctif (en changeant de temps et de personne pour que la distinction soit audible: "C'est la chose la plus intéressante qu'il ait trouvée", "C'est la seule personne qu'il ait aimée", etc. Dans la deuxième phrase en particulier, j'ai du mal à 1/2

Comment: accepter l'indicatif (2/2)

Comment: @aCOSwt Je crois que l'analyse faite par la BDL correspond en ce qui concerne  **le superlatif** et « **le seul** » parfaitement bien à l'usage français traditionnel; le subjonctif est le temps que j'ai trouvé et que j'ai utilisé toute une vie. Qu'il y ait dans le français contemporain une impulsion pour du changement est une autre histoire : il y a une possibilité d'utiliser l'indicatif et selon mon opinion elle ne soulève pas d'objection du point de vue logique. La BDL mentionne bien cette possibilité mais indique aussi qu'elle est minoritaire; une majorité préfère encore le subjonctif.

Comment: @aCOSwt On ne peut nier cela à l'apprenant, qui sera lui aussi bientôt capable de faire son choix, ni d'emblée le former à des pratiques assez arbitraires fondées sur un choix personnel. Il est préférable que l'apprenant soit exposé aux deux courants d'idée.